# How can I change the behavior of single letters in an environment?

Tags: environments, characters, extended-characters

I'm working with a Ktunaxa, a First Nations language that uses the symbols `ȼ` and `ⱡ` (and the uppercase equivalents `Ȼ` and `Ⱡ`, but not `c` or `l`.

How can I create an enivronment that would change all `c` and `l` to `ȼ` and `ⱡ`?

I'm aware I could create commands for the individual letters, but I'll usually be switching between English and Ktunaxa, so it makes sense to define an environment to make my life a little easier.

---

I would like this code:

```
This text has big C's and little c's and also a capital L. {\kt Na xaⱡȼin} means \textit{this dog.}
```

To create an output like this:

This text has big C's and little c's and also a capital L. Na xaⱡȼin means *this dog*.

---

Unicode code points:
ȼ U+023C

Ȼ U+023B

ⱡ U+2C61

Ⱡ U+2C60

Comment: You could do this. But you might wanna look at XeTeX, for instance, where you can just use unicode input that would actually look quite a lot like your sample code

Comment: Please give an example of a font that features ȼ, ⱡ, Ȼ and Ⱡ.

Comment: @Au101 - I think the OP's issue is that he/she may not have a keyboard that makes entering `ȼ`, `Ȼ`, `ⱡ`, and `Ⱡ` particularly straightforward. Hence, he/she is looking for a solution in which LaTeX does an automatic conversion of `c`, `C`, `l`, and `L` to  `ȼ`, `Ȼ`, `ⱡ`, and `Ⱡ` within a certain environment.

Comment: Thanks for the XeTeX idea, I forgot about it and have been meaning to learn about it for a while. I'd still be interested in an answer for curiosity's sake.

Comment: @Mico Arial has the characters.

Comment: @Au101 I've been trying to "just use unicode input," for a different situation, and nothing seems to work. Can you point me to a solution that would allow me to use Latin Extended B and C? I'm trying to use the opensans font, but I can't get XeTeX to display the characters.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use LuaLaTeX instead of either pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX, it's possible to set up a Lua function as well as TeX macros and environments -- named `\kt` and `ktenv` in the example code below -- that perform an automated conversion of `c`, `C`, `l`, and `L` to `ȼ`, `Ȼ`, `ⱡ`, and `Ⱡ`, respectively.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function kt ( s )
    s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "c", "ȼ" )
    s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "C", "Ȼ" )
    s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "l", "ⱡ" )
    s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "L", "Ⱡ" )
    return ( s )
end
\end{luacode} 
\newcommand\kt[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(kt(\luastring{#1}))}}
\newenvironment{ktenv}{%
   \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", kt, "kt")}}{%
   \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback( "process_input_buffer", "kt")}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial} % features ȼ, Ȼ, ⱡ, and Ⱡ 
\begin{document}
Na xalcin, c C l L

\kt{Na xalcin, c C l L}

\begin{ktenv}
Na xalcin, c C l L
\end{ktenv}

Na xalcin, c C l L
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For XeLaTeX, prepare a file `ktunaxa.map` containing

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "ktunaxa"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

; additions for Ktunaxa
U+0043 <> U+023B ; C -> LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH STROKE
U+0063 <> U+023C ; c -> LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH STROKE
U+004C <> U+2C60 ; L -> LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH DOUBLE BAR
U+006C <> U+2C61 ; l -> LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH DOUBLE BAR
```

and run `teckit_compile ktunaxa.map`, which will write a file `ktunaxa.tec` in the current directory.

In the same directory, prepare the test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\ktunaxafont}[Mapping=ktunaxa]{Linux Libertine O}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textkt}{\ktunaxafont}

\begin{document}

This text has big C's and little c's and also
a capital L. \textkt{Na xaⱡȼin} means \textit{this dog.}

This text has big C's and little c's and also
a capital L. \textkt{Na xalcin} means \textit{this dog.}

\textkt{CcLl}

\end{document}
```

Run XeLaTeX; the output, provided the font has the required glyphs, will be

[image]

There is no need that the fonts are the same; in the `\newfontfamily` declaration you can use any font having the glyphs for the language.

You can place your new `.tec` file (and also the `.map` source) in the directory

```
$TEXMFHOME/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/ktunaxa/
```

(create the tree), where `$TEXMFHOME` stands for the personal tree; for TeX Live it is `~/texmf`, for MacTeX it is `~/Library/texmf`. For MiKTeX there are similar methods.

You can also use `$TEXMFLOCAL`, but this requires also `mktexlsr`.

An automated way for building the structure and moving the files is, assuming a Bash shell

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME)/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/ktunaxa
mv ktunaxa.{map,tec} $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME)/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/ktunaxa/
```